# Unable to use compiled netlib BLAS on mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc, blas

I'm trying to make [a repository](https://github.com/Foadsf/Cmathtuts) collecting all the examples, tutorials and instructions I could find on the internet for C mathematical and algebra libraries (BLAS, CBLAS, LAPACK, CLAPACK, LAPACKE, ATLAS, openblas, GSL...). but it seems that I just can't get the compiled BLAS .a files working on mac OS X.

So far I have been able to compile BLAS and use it on ubuntu:

1. BLAS source code from netlib website downloaded and compiled (rename blas_LINUX.a to libblas.a)
2. Then I can compile the C file on ubuntu using the command below:

   `gcc foo.c path/to/libblas.a`

On my mac OS X (EL Capitan), I can compile BLAS (changing LINUX in the make.inc to DARWIN), but when I try to compile a C code using the command above I get errors like below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ddot_", referenced from:
      _main in foo-3a35db.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

("*ddot*" part differs for different functions)

possibilities:

1. Maybe I'm not compiling the library correctly on mac and there are some differences I'm not aware of
2. The builtin Accelerate framework of mac OS X is messing up with the compiling process

P.S. Guys I know BLAS/LAPACK is already built into the mac OS X Accelerate framework and I can easily compile using the command `gcc foo.c -lblas` or `gcc foo.c -framework Accelerate` but I want to use the compiled .a from netlib. I want to know why it works properly on ubuntu but not mac OS X?

P.S.2. Please notice that I can compile the source code successfully without any errors on mac OS X. I just can use it!

Example code: [source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1740797)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double ddot_(const int *N, const double *a, const int *inca, const double *b, const int *incb);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  double *a = (double *)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
  a[0] = 1.0;
  a[1] = 2.0;
  a[2] = 3.0;
  // on the stack
  double b[3] = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0};

  int N = 3, one = 1; // one really doesn't look good in C

  double dot_product = ddot_(&N, a, &one, b, &one);
  printf(" The dot product is: %f \n", dot_product);

  return 0;
}
```

(edit1) solution:

1. open make.inc
2. change the line `OPTS     = -O3` to `OPTS     = -O3 -pipe -c` and make.

(edit2): better solution:
since I asked this question I have realised that I have been doing everything wrong. Netlib BLAS is actually a collection of fortran routines/subroutines/functions. and the Makefile in the source code just gives us a static library libblas.a which is a collection of all .o object files  compiled with gfortran. when we want to compile a C code which want to call one of those routines, we also need to link to the gfortran library libgfortran.* so if you have gcc installed (brew install gcc). look for libgfrotran* (`sudo find / -name "libgfortrn.*"`) and then link your gcc to this folder too. to make it easy I put a Makefile here:

```
all:
    gcc -c foo.c
    gcc -o bar.out foo.o -L path/to/libgfortran.*/ -lgfortran -L path/to/libblas.a -lblas
```

or alternatively compile the code directly with gfortran:

```
all:
    gcc -c foo.c
    gfortran -o bar.out foo.o -L path/to/libblas.a -lblas
```

or simply compile with:

```
gcc foo.c bar.out -L path/to/libblas.a -lblas -L path/to/libgfortran.*/ -lgfortran
```

the wonder is how/why the former solution actually worked and why on ubuntu you don't have to link to -lgfortran!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you compiled BLAS library from Netlib with compiler options that changed the mangling scheme of Fortran routines.

By default, Netlib's `make.inc` uses `gfortran` to compile BLAS:

```
$ grep FORTRAN make.inc
#  Modify the FORTRAN and OPTS definitions to refer to the
FORTRAN  = gfortran
```

It is compiled without any flags:

```
gfortran -O3 -pipe -c ddot.f -o ddot.o
```

and you get the `ddot()` routine:

```
$ grep -i ddot ddot.o libblas.a 
Binary file ddot.o matches
Binary file libblas.a matches
```

And you can find it with the command line tools:

```
$ nm ddot.o libblas.a | grep -i ddot
ddot.o:
0000000000000000 T _ddot_
libblas.a(ddot.o):
0000000000000000 T _ddot_
```

Your example compiles with the library:

```
cc ex.c libblas.a
```

or with the `ddot.o` file:

```
cc -pipe ex.c ddot.o
```

I cannot reproduce your problem. You should use the `nm` and `grep` commands to find out what happened to the name of the `ddot()` routine.

PS. Your code has extra semicolon `;` after the end of definition of `main()`.

Comment: I think I managed to solve the problem using the flags you just gave. It seems that by adding the flags  `-pipe -c` to the `make.inc` file now the BLAS library is compiled correctly and I can use it to compile other C code. I'm going to try it more. I will report it here

Comment: Don't worry about `-pipe` (this means: don't create temporary files in `/tmp` but use UNIX pipes to communicate between compiler and linker tool chain). The `-c' flag just means _compile-only_ (don't link or try to create an executable binary).

Comment: yes actually I was completely wrong. I added more details to the post. would you mind checking it and letting me know if it is correct or not?